# Ad hoc way of setting up containers in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am new to AWS, and was wondering if I could leverage the services provided by AWS to spin up container on the fly. My current situation is- I have some dynamic(changing) environment variables that is required to run the container. The number of containers is also unknown to me, so I am confused about ECS definitions too. The number of containers may be 0 or be 100, and each of the container has different env. Also, is it possible to delete the container after use.

I looked into AWS ESC and fargate and honestly I am overwhelmed by all the new stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single ECS Task Definition for your containers, and then spin up an arbitrary number of containers (tasks) from that Task Definition via the ECS [Run Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) API, with different environment variables using the [Container Override](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerOverride.html) feature.